# How do I extract NetCDF monthly summed totals for a given longitude/latitude?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I've downloaded a NetCDF file that contains monthly summed totals of rainfall over Sierra Leone.

I want to extract a time series of these monthly sums for a specific set of coordinates over the year period, so I'm expecting to have 12 values in total. Here's what I've tried.

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('era_monthly_yr2018.nc')*1000

lon_freetown = -13
lat_freetown = 8

df = ds.sel(latitude=(lat_freetown), longitude=(lon_freetown), method='nearest').to_dataframe()
df = df.drop('longitude',1)
df = df.drop('latitude',1)
df1 = df.reset_index()
```

```
print(df)

           longitude  latitude         tp
time                                      
2018-01-01      -13.0       8.0   0.096221
2018-02-01      -13.0       8.0   0.043679
2018-03-01      -13.0       8.0   0.875490
2018-04-01      -13.0       8.0   1.571830
2018-05-01      -13.0       8.0   4.642695
2018-06-01      -13.0       8.0  24.877733
2018-07-01      -13.0       8.0  21.150408
2018-08-01      -13.0       8.0  14.919422
2018-09-01      -13.0       8.0  22.914684
2018-10-01      -13.0       8.0   5.977770
2018-11-01      -13.0       8.0   3.168352
2018-12-01      -13.0       8.0   0.894481
```

```
print(df1)

       time         tp
0  2018-01-01   0.096221
1  2018-02-01   0.043679
2  2018-03-01   0.875490
3  2018-04-01   1.571830
4  2018-05-01   4.642695
5  2018-06-01  24.877733
6  2018-07-01  21.150408
7  2018-08-01  14.919422
8  2018-09-01  22.914684
9  2018-10-01   5.977770
10 2018-11-01   3.168352
11 2018-12-01   0.894481
```

However, the result I get isn't what I'm expecting. The rainfall is much lower than expected which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Has anyone worked with monthly NetCDF files before and know where I could be going wrong? Alternatively, I have the same data in an hourly format, but can't figure out how I'd obtain monthly sums from this

Comment: add output of print(df1) and print df

Comment: just updated the question to add them

Comment: I think that you did the field mean of your study area

Comment: What you have there should be correct